# Как сгенерировать случайную строку, которое не будет начинаться с определённой цифры?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, случайные-числа

Есть примерный код:

```
import random
import string

number = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for i in range(5))

print(number)
```

Мне необходимо, чтобы генерировалось выражение, которое никогда не будет начинаться с определённой цифры (Например "0")

Причём генерироваться будет много раз. Поэтому нужно, чтобы сразу верное было

```
Пример: 
"0hsf3" - Такое мне не нужно
"g0se2" - А вот такое в самый раз
```

Может есть какой-то модуль, который позволяет так сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
import string


number = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(5))
number = number.replace("0", random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase), 1) if number.startswith("0") else number
print(number)
```